# How do I detect if my code is being compiled with -fno-exceptions?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I'm writing a C++ library and I would like to make my API throw exceptions for invalid parameters, but rely on asserts instead when the code is compiled with `-fno-exceptions`.

Is there a way to detect at compile-time if I'm allowed to use exception handling? 
Note that I'm writing a header-only library, so I don't have a `configure` phase and I don't have access to the build system to simply define a macro on the command line (and
I don't want to add burden to the user).

Since the Standard doesn't have any concept of "-fno-exceptions", of course the solution could be compiler-dependent. In this case I'm interested in solutions that work with both g++ and clang++, other compilers are not important for this project.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 26, accepted):

GCC and Clang define the `__EXCEPTIONS` macro when exceptions are enabled, and do not define it when exceptions are disabled *via* `-fno-exceptions`.

Example:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
#ifdef __EXCEPTIONS
    puts("Exceptions are enabled");
#else
    puts("Exceptions are disabled");
#endif
}
```